# Send request as Json on UWP

Tags: c#, json, uwp, dotnet-httpclient, azure-machine-learning-service

I have deployed an AzureML published experiment with deployed web service. I tried to use the [sample code provided in the configuration page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-consume-web-services/), but universal apps do not implement Http.Formatting yet, thus I couldn't use [postasjsonasync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx).

I tried to follow the sample code as much as possible, but I'm getting statuscode of 415 "Unsupported Media Type", What's the mistake I'm doing?

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);
// client.BaseAddress = uri;

var scoreRequest = new
{
            Inputs = new Dictionary<string, StringTable>() {
                    {
                        "dataInput",
                        new StringTable()
                        {
                            ColumnNames = new [] {"Direction", "meanX", "meanY", "meanZ"},
                            Values = new [,] {  { "", x.ToString(), y.ToString(), z.ToString() },  }
                        }
                    },
                },
            GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() { }
 };
 var stringContent = new StringContent(scoreRequest.ToString());
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to serialize the object to a JSON string (I recommend using NewtonSoft.Json to make it easier) and set the content type accordingly. Here's an implementation I'm using in my UWP apps (note that `_client` is an `HttpClient`):

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync<T>(Uri uri, T item)
    {
        var itemAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
        var content = new StringContent(itemAsJson);
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        return await _client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    }
```